# Excel-VBA: Filter/sort "complex" data

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to find a way to filter and/or sort certain data in Excel without any luck.

In column B I have several thousand cells of data.

Some examples of data in the cells

```
BP18529
AUG987
AG723KK
DERT429
732KSM
```

These are just examples, there are many more and also with varying mixtures of letters and numbers.

What I would like to do is filter/remove all the cells that contains this format BP18529; as in not that specific data but all cells starting with two letters and ending with five numbers.

I cannot install any addons. Thinking I should be able to do this with a VBA script?

Comment: I ment for the information to be on different lines,

BP18529,
AUG987,
AG723KK,
DERT429,
732KSM

Comment: What did you try so far? Should not be too hard to loop through the data and check when length is 7 if left 2 characters are not numeric and right 5 characters are numeric with `IsNumeric()`. Please try and show the code you already have in your original question.

Comment: Does it have to be in VBA? I would just add some extra columns that checks each character using MID strings (using ISTEXT or ISNUMBER) and then AND formula at the end then just filter on True/False in the AND column.

Comment: Are you clearing the contents or deleting the entire row when found?

Comment: It certainly does not have to be in VBA, I'd just like it solved in whatever fashion - I just thought it probably would have to be in VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this

```
Sub main()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1 ' loop through columns B cells from last not empty one backwards
        If IsToDelete(Cells(i, 2).Text) Then Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete ' if current cell satisfy deletion criteria then delete its entire row
    Next
End Sub

Function IsToDelete(Txt As String) As Boolean
    Select Case Asc(UCase(Mid(Txt, 1, 1))) ' check if first character is a letter
        Case 65 To 90
        Select Case Asc(UCase(Mid(Txt, 2, 1))) ' check if second character is a letter
            Case 65 To 90
            Select Case Asc(Mid(Txt, 3, 1)) ' check if third character is a number
                Case 48 To 59
                    IsToDelete = IsNumeric(Right(Txt, 5)) ' mark for deletion if last 5 characters are a number
            End Select
        End Select
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: @John, any feedback?

Comment: Sorry for the slow answer. I just got back to work. This seems to work flawlessly! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to loop through all the data to check each cell. Because you want to delete rows you need to loop backwards otherwise you would change the row numbers and the loop wont count correctly.

With `IsNumeric()` you can easily check if the left 2 characters are not numeric and the right 5 characters are numeric.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteSpecificDataItems()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Tabelle5") 'define which worksheet

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column B

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = lRow To 1 Step -1 'loop backwards
        Dim iCell As Range
        Set iCell = ws.Cells(iRow, "B")

        If Len(iCell.Value) = 7 Then 'check if length = 7
            'chech if left 2 characters are not numeric AND right 5 characters are numeric
            If Not IsNumeric(Left$(iCell.Value, 1)) And Not IsNumeric(Mid$(iCell.Value, 2, 1)) And IsNumeric(Right$(iCell.Value, 5)) Then
                iCell.EntireRow.Delete 'delete row
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

End Sub
```

You might want to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False/True` to make it a little faster.

Comment: This also worked flawlessly, sir! Thank you very much, the Application.ScreenUpdating = False setting did make it instant, opposed to spending some time "working through it". In the end the results were the exact same as the script from DisplayName. 

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim unionRng As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("B1") 'change to range required

    Dim currCell As Range

    For Each currCell In rng

        If PatternFound(currCell.Text) Then

            If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, currCell)
            Else
                Set unionRng = currCell
            End If

        End If

    Next currCell

    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.ClearContents ' or unionRng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub

Public Function PatternFound(ByVal Txt As String) As Boolean

    Application.Volatile
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim matches As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBSCRIPT.REGEXP")

    With regex

      .Pattern = "[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5}"
      .Global = True
      .MultiLine = True
      .IgnoreCase = True
       Set matches = .Execute(Txt)
   End With

   If matches.Count > 0 Then PatternFound = True

End Function
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the help. It worked, ish. For some reason, it missed six cells with values that should have been deleted. As far as I can tell it also deleted one cell that should not have been deleted, as it contained three letters followed by five numbers. The lines from DisplayName seemed to work like it should. 

I much appreciate the help though, your way of solving this was more in the lines of how I was thinking of doing it too.